# Empty stack with one recursive method and one iterative method

Tags: java

This a question from an old test I am practicing on.

*Write one method **void empty(Stack s)** in Java that empties one stack (the input parameter).
The method should be written in two versions, one recursive and one iterative. 
Use the methods **void push(E element)**, **E pop()** and **boolean isEmpty()** that exist in the generic class Stack where E is a class.*

So, I tried to write the recursive version, and it seemed to work when I tested it. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could start the iterative version or improve the recursive version?

```
//recursive
void empty(Stack<String> s) {
    if (!s.isEmpty()){
        s.pop();
        empty(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a loop instead for iterative?

Comment: Start of iterative version: `while`

Comment: *"what do you think?"* Sounds like a question that should have been posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, so with "iterative" they are referring to  loops like for-, and while-loops?

Comment: @DanielAndersson yes, that is iterative, it's repeting an operation on  something

Comment: @DanielAndersson Yes, and do-while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Just replace the contents of your method with:

```
while(!s.isEmpty()) {
    s.pop();
}
```

This iterates while the stack is not empty, removing elements from the stack.

Additionally, your question specifies to use the generic `Stack` methods to empty a stack. If such is the case, you might want to change your method signature to the following:

```
void <T> empty(Stack<T> s) {
```

This means that your empty method can take a `Stack<T>` of arbitrary generic type `T`, rather than just a `Stack<String>`(Stack of String).

Comment: Can also use `!s.empty()` to save two letters!  Not much of a point, but `Stack` has duplicated methods funnily enough.

Comment: @Nexevis I believe that `isEmpty` would communicate the intent better :) `empty` sounds like `clear` to me.

Comment: Yeah true, I think your way is better, I just thought it was an interesting thing to note in a comment, not an answer.